# проблема с view model

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

выглядит так:

```
open class EditViewModel : ViewModel(){
    val text : MutableLiveData<note> by lazy {
    MutableLiveData<note>()
}
}
```

инициализирую фрагменте так:

```
    private val vm = activityViewModels<EditViewModel>()
```

и проблема в том что переменная text не видна андроид студио он жалуется что такой нет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: где именно не видна?

Comment: Ну так у неё же выставлен доступ `private` - естественно она не видна за пределами своего класса

Comment: в фрагменте и в активити пытался тоже не видна

Comment: ошибка в примере там его нет

Comment: ``vm`` это ``activityViewModels``, а ``text`` в ``EditViewModel``

Comment: `private val vm = activityViewModels<EditViewModel>()` -> `private val vm by activityViewModels<EditViewModel>()`